# How can I able to handle both GET and POST requests in views.py in python vue js?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

My views.py is

```
def searchnew(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    loc = request.POST.get('location')
    d = {
    'name': name,
    'loc' : loc,

    }
    return render(request,"searchnew.html",d)
else:
     name = request.GET.get('name')
      na = {
    'name': name,

    }
     return render(request,"searchnew.html",na)
```

I have GET request and other POST request. How can I able to handle GET request in this case?

This is my GET request

```
<a v-bind:href="'searchnew/?name='+post.name">{{post.name}}</a>
```

I am getting error as 
IndentationError: unexpected indent

How can I able to pass this name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def searchnew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        loc = request.POST.get('location')
        d = {
            'name': name,
            'loc': loc,

        }
        return render(request, "searchnew.html", d)
    else:
    # do the thing you want to do in GET method
        name = request.GET.get('name')
        na = {
           'name': name,
        }
        return render(request,"searchnew.html",na)
```

Comment: There could be other methods like 'PUT' so providing functionality for GET inside else wouldn't be okay.

Comment: def searchnew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        loc = request.POST.get('location')
        d = {
        'name': name,
        'loc' : loc,

        }
        return render(request,"searchnew.html",d)
    else:
      name = request.GET.get('name')
       na = {
        'name': name,

        }
         return render(request,"searchnew.html",na)

Comment: I tried this.. but getting error as IndentationError: unexpected indent